# R make groups of n of subgroups (supergroup)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a `tibble` with n items (e.g. 80) with multiple occurrences

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(2323)
data <- tibble(item=rep(paste("item",1:80),sample(1:10,80, replace=T)))

data %>% group_by(item)
# A tibble: 407 x 1
   item  
   <chr> 
 1 item 1
 2 item 1
 3 item 1
 4 item 2
 5 item 2
 6 item 2
 7 item 2
 8 item 2
 9 item 2
10 item 2
# ... with 397 more rows
```

Now I would like to add a grouping column (`supergroup`) which groups n subgroups together (e.g. items 1-4 = supergroup 1 etc.).

Desired `tibble`:

```
 A tibble: 407 x 2
   item   supergroup
   <chr>       <int>
  item 1          1
  item 1          1
  item 1          1
  item 2          1
...
  item 5          2
  item 5          2
  item 5          2
  item 5          2
  item 5          2
```

## Update:

I think something like this will do the trick, however, I am stuck with the alphanumeric nature of `item` and [this](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2159) does not help

```
n=4
data %>%      
mutate(supergroup=group_indices(group_by(.,item = ntile(item, length(unique(data$item))/n))))
# A tibble: 407 x 2
   item   supergroup
   <chr>       <int>
 1 item 1          1
 2 item 1          1
 3 item 1          1
 4 item 2          3
 5 item 2          3
 6 item 2          3
 7 item 2          3
 8 item 2          3
 9 item 2          3
10 item 2          3
# ... with 397 more rows
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is supergroup actually the right term?

Answer (score 0):

```
n=4

data %>% 
  mutate(item=factor(item,levels=unique(item))) %>% 
  group_by(item) %>% 
  mutate(nr=group_indices()) %>% 
  mutate(supergroup=as.numeric(cut(nr,seq(0,length(unique(.$nr)),n))))
```

using `cut` worked out, however, there is probably an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
data %>% group_by(item)
#
len=4
#
data %>%    
  mutate(tmp=as.numeric(gsub("item|\\s","",item))) %>%
  mutate(supergroup = ntile(tmp, length(unique(data$item))/len)) %>% select(item,supergroup)
```

> Output head()

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  item   supergroup
  <chr>       <int>
1 item 1          1
2 item 1          1
3 item 1          1
4 item 2          1
5 item 2          1
6 item 2          1
```

> Output tail()

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  item    supergroup
  <chr>        <int>
1 item 80         20
2 item 80         20
3 item 80         20
4 item 80         20
5 item 80         20
6 item 80         20
```